# Which file format should I use for storing short[]

Tags: java, android

I have some very long `short[]`, some multidimensional, which I want to store in some file in my Android App. At first I tried to store these arrays in a Java Class, but it returned a "code too large" error.

Therefore I now have to find a new file format to store these arrays in (pre compile), where the values can be stored as `short`s to save space.

Which file format do you recommend, and how would I go about reading from it, from my application?

Answer (score 0):

1) If it's some repeated data - use sqlite
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html

2) if you still prefer file
use DataOutputStream
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/DataOutputStream.html

3)
You can serialize array and save it to a file
[How do I serialize an object and save it to a file in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4118751/how-do-i-serialize-an-object-and-save-it-to-a-file-in-android)

Comment: That second one seems interesting, but how do I co about writing this data pre compile?

Comment: Use temp util java program to prepare and write the data to file. Then load it on startup at your app.

Comment: Ok, so I can write a program i normal (non-android) java using DataOutputStream to write the data to a file, and then put that in file in my res/raw folder in my android project, and read it with DataInputStream?

Comment: Seems like a fine solution, testing it out with this example:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26072482/write-int-to-file-using-dataoutputstreamhttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/26072482/write-int-to-file-using-dataoutputstream